# Laravel 7- Carbon return ever time as UTC

Tags: laravel

This is a real stranger, when return the current time with Carbon, this is return ever time as UTC for me.
I do not understand why if I config as Europe/Madrid everything.

Example:

```
return Carbon::now() 
The result is 2020-07-06 14:30:00
```

But is:

```
dd(Carbon::now())

The result is 2020-07-06 16:30:00
```

I not understand why.

My file app.php

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Madrid',
```

And when load a model for example user

```
$user = User::find(1);
```

The created_at and updated_at return

```
2020-06-07 14:35:00
```

But in database the value saved is

```
2020-06-07 16:35:00
```

[image]

Comment: do you clear the cache after changing the timezone in app.php file??

Comment: Yes, clear cache and result is some, I using Docker, my php, database and nginx is configurated with Europe/Madrid

Comment: Same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62798761/laravel-carbon-timezone

Answer (score 1):

Carbon uses the default DateTime PHP object.
You can set custom timezone as :

```
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $tz, 'Europe/Madrid');
```

In the `AppServiceProvider.php` you can add the php functionality to alter the timestamp for the whole project :

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
}
```

Comment: The result is same, adding the date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');