# Laravel + Carbon + Timezone

Tags: laravel, timezone

I have configured the timezone in `config/app.php` to `Europe/Lisbon`.

If I do a `return date_default_timezone_get();`, It returns `Europe/Lisbon` like I want.

So far so good!

When I do `Carbon::now()` it returns for example 16 hour while the current time is 17h. Can someone explain why the daylight saving aren't considered?

I'm using Laravel 7.16, PHP 7.4

Regards

EDIT 1: Code image + Times | https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMFVL.jpg

EDIT 2: always done `php artisan optimize:clear` to clear all caches when I change something in the config.

EDIT 3: created_at and updated_at on models are getting correct times.

EDIT 4: `return Carbon::now()` returns bad hours. Doing `dd(Carbon::now())` returns the correct values, with the Timezone configured in `config/app.php` | dd() example -> `date: 2020-07-08 17:25:28.935949 Europe/Lisbon (+01:00)`

EDIT 5: Opened an issue at github -
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/33475

EDIT 6: In my case, I used the php date() function to workaround the problem. Not the way I wanted but does the job...

```php
if (date(now()) > $subscriber->token_expire_date)
{
    // return not found response
    return $this->response(false, 410, 'The token has expired.', []);
}
```

Comment: Carbon is UTC based therefore simply doing `Carbon::now()` will output the time in UTC format. You have to specify the timezone for an accurate reflection of the dateTime in your city or area. `Carbon::now('PST')` OR `Carbon::now('Continent/City')` like `(Carbon::now('America/Montreal')` for example

Comment: @STA, thanks but already tried this and doesn't work. Even if I change to America.

Comment: Can you tell me, which Laravel version you are using?

Comment: @STA is correct here, under any circumstance Carbon::now('Europe/Lisbon'); Should give you the time in Lisbon.

Comment: Check updated question please.

Comment: Do you get the same on `return Carbon::now()` and `dd(Carbon::now())`???

Comment: @Kurt seems like it a glitch on newer version, another same question  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758417/laravel-7-carbon-return-ever-time-as-utc/62758619?noredirect=1#comment110984137_62758619

Comment: This is a really odd issue. Hope someone can shine some light on it. Deserves some big upvotes here.

Comment: you can use date() function to help you with getting the correct time date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
echo date("YmdHis"); https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.

Comment: @hmrneves Tengo el mismo problema, lo has llegado a solucionar?

Comment: @Alexd2, no, I couldn't

Comment: @hmrneves but this is a error of Carbon 2?

Comment: @Alexd2, yes...

Answer (score 6):

Carbon uses the default **DateTime** PHP object, so use the **date_default_timezone_set()** function, for example: date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

or you define it `AppServiceProvider` `App/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
}
```

Or you can use `setTimezone` of carbon method

```
echo Carbon::now()->setTimezone('Europe/Lisbon')->format('H:i');
```

Comment: thanks, but didn't work. I'm testing with American timezones hopping to get different values but I don't.

Comment: This works for my previous version 5.x. but not in Laravel 7.x.  I think there are a glich on Laravel 7. Dont idea about 6.x